# Missing File After MV command

Tags: mv

I typed a command to refactor my file from the current folder I was in to another folder.

What I wanted was:
mv /var/backup /var/www/backup

However, I typed:
mv /var/backup /var/www/

Now I can't seem to find my file anywhere! Is there a way I can recover it?

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/www`? It should be there as long as the `/var/www` directory existed. If it did not, your file has been renamed to `/var/www`.

Answer (score 1):

If some error happened, `mv` prints an error message and returns a non-zero status.

If `mv` didn't print anything then the move happened as you wrote it:

- If `/var/www` did not exist, then you renamed `/var/backup` to `/var/www`.
- If `/var/www` was an existing directory, then you moved `/var/backup` to `/var/www/backup`.

If neither of these happened, then either you typed a different command or you (or someone else) did something else to those files afterwards.